# Generating excel files in SAS - wrong encoding - special chars missing

Tags: excel, csv, sas, export, xls

When I am exporting data to Excel by SAS process right encoding is missing. 
I have two environments with same metadata configuration. I've checked sasv9 for SAS 9.4 and WS and it's setup correctly, same as previous environment where it's exporting correctly. 
I CAN'T CHANGE SOURCE CODE OF THIS PROCESS.
Have you any idea where I can find encoding settings?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same program, run by two different SAS installations, is producing different output files you will want to compare the options of the two SAS sessions and identify the differences.

`Proc OPTIONS` will log all options in effect:

```
* all options;
proc options;
run;

* limit logging to just language related options;
proc options group=languagecontrol;
run;
```

Since you can't change the source code of the program, you will need to change the startup options of the 'new' environment to match those of the 'old' environment.

Note: You can also add `-VERBOSE` to the SAS start command or (SAS config file) to have the options logged at startup.